# Possible to configure Health Check for Azure Functions with Terraform?

Tags: azure-functions, terraform

I have Terraform deploying Azure Functions. Now I would like to add health check with Terraform?
How to enable it, add url and time?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Health Check** gets automatically enabled if you set the `path for health check` under  `site_config block`. But there is no parameter to configure the `load balancing time` from terraform.

**I tested it by adding the site_config block with health_check_path:**

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "terraform-azure-functions"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  site_config{
  health_check_path          = "/api/health" # need to configure for enabling Health check
  }
}
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]